# como poner null en excel si la celda esta vacia?

Tags: excel

Quiero agregarle el valor de NULL a mi celda si se encuentra vacia, y si contiene un valor que permanezca ese mismo valor. Se que existe la propiedad si(esblanco) pero yo necesito hacerlo sobre la misma columna, es decir si en mi columna tengo los valores, 5,4,3,sin valor, 1, sin valor. Quiero que mi función mantenga esos valores en las celdas y donde no existe ningun tipo de dato que me ponga la palabra null.

Comment: Lo que buscas para devolver algo cuando la celda esta vacia seria =ISBLANK(A1) , te devolvería True.

Comment: No porque es para devolver un valor en otra celda yo lo necesito en la misma celda donde esta en blanco @AleBuo

Comment: ¿Puedes usar VBA o lo necesitas hacer con fórmulas?

Comment: Las celdas vacías son nulas de por sí. ¿No puedes comprobar aquellas que tengan longitud cero?

Answer (score 1):

suponiendo que puedas utilizar macros, selecciona el rango y prueba lo siguiente:

```
Sub es_null()
For Each celda In Selection
    If Len(ActiveCell) > 0 Then
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
    Else
    ActiveCell.Value = "NULL"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Ahora si lo que se quiere es un valor null, prueba pasándolo por una carga de Power Query, por defecto las celdas sin información quedaran como null, ya puedes hacer la transformación en el editor de Power Query y retornarlas en otra hoja.